# Rails 4 to_json include all associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

so I know how to include a specific association:

```
obj.to_json include: :some_association_name
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to blindly include all associations and not have to list each one individually. I optimistically tried:

```
obj.to_json include: :all
```

That didn't work, of course. Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
obj.to_json(include: obj.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name))
```

Comment: bingo. thanks. I was looking for a way to find the list of associations, but when it wasn't what I expected, 'associations', I went down a different path. I gave up too soon. thanks for your help!